# HTML Javascript Calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

I have been trying to integrate a simple calender into my website but i am not able to find any good one yet due to which i am posting this question.

All i need in the calender is that i can mark up dates and when user click on that he will be able to see the event against that mark in a popup or the like. Kindly let me know is there any such open source calender available which provides such a functionality on JS and  html? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks,

Comment: are you looking for google like calendar? If so check http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn what kinds of questions should and shouldn't be asked here. This question is not really appropriate here, since it's not specific enough and lacks a "right" answer. Your best bet is to use Google to search for different JavaScript-driven calendar or event plugins until you find one that suits your requirements.

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks for -1 this question deserves that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the datepicker for your needs like this. This is nearly the best out there.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

This displays the datepicker inline

Comment: no doubt it is good but there's not any example of marked up dates and when user click on those can see its respective notification

Comment: You can have multiple dropdowns and events fired the...but I think the  other plugin suffices if you want to show the selection graphically

Comment: i found a great tutorial of how to mark dates and the like on one of the answers of stackoverflow, thanks for giving me the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look Fullcalendar. It a awesome calendar it my help you too. I have used in some of my projects and it is great.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

You can add, remove and update events, import events from google calendar, drag and drop functionality, monthly, weekly and daily views, etc.

Also, if you like any jqueryui theme roller you can add to it.

Comment: no doubt it is good but its extremely large... but thanks i can use it now for larger view...

Comment: you can it smaller, just add the calendar in an div with small width

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI has an excellent date picker that should satisfy your requirements. [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: can i markup dates and mention event against those dates in it?

Comment: You should be able to do anything you like, it's a widget that you can freely modify to fit your own needs. However if you are looking for a full blown calendar widget you may need to do some searching.